# How could I go about getting this animated background effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to make my website a live background of space.  I am attempting to get the stars to spawn on the left of the screen and slowly move over.  And occasionally their will be stars that come in from other directions.  My question is, how should I go about doing this?

Would it be smartest to make a Javascript, script that would make a LOT of `<div>`'s and then move them all randomly?  Or would it be smartest to use a canvas?  I've never used a canvas before so I don't know all it's uses yet.

Here's a link to the effect I'm trying to emulate (It's a YouTube video with music) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8MsE-4dygY&list=PL21A7A915E7020E73&index=16 
I'm trying to emulate what the stars or partices are doing in the background of that video, so how should I go about this?  (I'm not asking for all the code, I'm just making that clear.)  Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: A few eeks ago, i've came across something exactly what you're looking for.. Can't find it anymore I'm sorry..

Comment: fabio has exactly what your looking for

Comment: I've created stars to spawn on random parts of the screen.  I'm working on now making them all move separate ways randomly.  Only thing is I'm using a LOT of `<div>`'s, which I'm pretty sure isn't that great of a thing.

Comment: And, @Bokdem if you ever come across it again, it would be great if you could let me know... For research purposes, of course. :)

Comment: Tim Poon has written a nice blog post on how to create an animating starfield using html canvas: http://timothypoon.com/blog/2011/01/19/html5-canvas-particle-animation/

Answer (score 1):

well, you can obviously use a Parallax background with some overlays for an easy effect, but you can go further by using any of the many scripts out there, search Google for that. Or you can learn how to do it via scripting with this [great tutorial](http://www.script-tutorials.com/night-sky-with-twinkling-stars/) that makes use of HTML5 and CSS3

Comment: Thanks, that's gonna be a lot of help..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Canvas may be more performant than adding lots of divs as you won't need to create a large DOM tree. DOM operations are expensive and can cause memory thrashing if you repeatedly create and destroy lots of elements. Using multiple overlaid images and CSS3 translate transitions should be more performant still, but may make it harder to achieve all the effects that you want - randomized movement, separation of stars on the same plane, etc. etc.